# Image Morphing in C#

Tags: c#, image, gdi, morphing

I am looking for any example code or libraries to perform image morphing in C#. For example, taking two images, defining common points and "merging" the features. My google search failed me, unless the only option is to write this from scratch? Many thanks

Comment: There are also tools to do that ... http://www.fantamorph.com/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps C++ is close enough ?

```
http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/~xmrm/
```

Answer (score 2):

[AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) has a morph filter. I don't know if it lets you define the point set or if it just does a "dumb" default, but worth a look anyway. I use AForge for lots of things- pretty slick, and free.

Comment: +1 for AForge.NET. It's awesome and actively being developed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at homographies. Its a way to merge the two images, given a common set (4 pairs) of points. If you want to match the two images by features you will need to use machine learning, techniques to detect the similarities. AForge has a few image processing techniques, and the necessary tools for machine learning.